# SQL: Using an INSERT within a SELECT statement

Tags: sql-server, xml, select, insert

I have a SQL SELECT statement that will create its results in XML Format. I would like to INSERT into another table (Log via insert) every time a row is selected from the original SELECT Statement. Is there anyway to include an INSERT Statement inside of a SELECT Statement?

```
    SELECT      cs_ads_StoreLocations.LocationGUID, *Bunch of Selects AS Distance 
FROM         *Bunch of Inter Joins*

WHERE     *Bunch of conditions*
ORDER BY *You don't want to know*
FOR XML AUTO

INSERT INTO cs_ads_StoreLog (LocationGUID) VALUES (*DISTINCT cs_ads_StoreLocations.LocationGUID from select statement above*)
```

This is just some sample code that has the INSERT outside of the SELECT statement. I need something that has it inside the SELECT Statement or another way of running an INSERT

Just to clarify. This sample code is part of a Stored Proc

Comment: Eric's answer is what i would have suggested, but you seem adamant about having the INSERT inside the SELECT - what is the reason behind this. 
Also it seems that you are thinking that you can perform some action for each row that is returned by the SELECT - don't forget this is set-based processing - the result of a SELECT is a SET of rows, not a collection of individual rows.

Answer (score 1):

`INSERT` will actually accept a `SELECT` as its input. You can just use this command (your `SELECT` copied as a subquery, though you could probably refactor it to return those distinct GUIDs without a subquery...but I'd need to see the whole monster).

```
insert into (cs_ads_StoreLog)
select distinct
    a.LocationGUID
from
    (SELECT
        cs_ads_StoreLocations.LocationGUID, *Bunch of Selects AS Distance 
    FROM
        *Bunch of Inter Joins*
    WHERE
        *Bunch of conditions*
    ORDER BY 
        *You don't want to know*
    ) a
```

Then, you can just return the `SELECT` that you have (it'll be cached, so you don't need to worry about performance hits too much).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps dynamic SQL would solve this? Example [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1160).
Or maybe you could store the values in a table var, and do your insert on that.

Comment: The sample code is part of a Stored Proc. I am just trying to find a way of including the INSERT into it.

Comment: Dynamic SQL and table variables can be used in SP's. FYI. :)