# SQL Server : INSERT INTO within a SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssrs-2008

In SSRS 2008, my query is in the form

```
WITH CTE ( *that makes a list of dates, unfortunately only starting from today, not from whatever past date the report demands*)
    SELECT 
        *a bunch of columns*
    FROM 
        asimpletable p1
    CROSS APPLY 
        (*CTE*) dates1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        (*demand list subquery with several selects pulling from several tables*) d1 ON (*simple.PartID AND CTE.demandDate*)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        (*supply list subquery with several selects pulling from several tables*) s1 ON (*yada*)  
    *..and 4 other joins to subqueries*
    WHERE 
        *enough conditions that I don't want to copy it 6 times for 6 different INSERT INTO statements*
```

Because the CTE can only start from today, when I display all the select by date, any that was dated in the past are lumped out of order.

So I want to make a temp table to cross apply and feed in all the dates I need.  I can see how to do it with 6 INSERT INTO, copying the joined subqueries, but not only would it look ugly, it would be worse to keep all the subqueries in sync.

I liked the sound of this, but can't see how to return the selects nor how to apply it to several subqueries https://stackoverflow.com/a/1101516/5612361.

Reason the CTE idea only starts from today:

```
SET @CTEStartDate = cast(getdate() as date); 
SET @CTEEndDate = cast(dateadd(day,100,getdate()) as date);

WITH Dates(eaDate) AS (
    SELECT @CTEStartDate AS eaDate  --Select First day in range
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, eaDate) FROM Dates WHERE eaDate < @CTEEndDate  --Add a record for every day in the range
)
```

When i try to use

```
SET @CTEStartDate = cast(dateadd(day,-30,getdate()) as date);
```

I get

> For more information about this error navigate to the report server on
>   the local server machine, or enable remote errors
>   ---------------------------- Cannot read the next data row for the dataset DataSet1. (rsErrorReadingNextDataRow)
>   ---------------------------- An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)

As soon as I take out that dateadd it resolves without a hitch.

Comment: Why does the CTE only start from today?

Comment: I added a note explaining it to the post.  If that can be fixed instead, I`ll take it.